# Selenium 2.53.6 not working in Firefox 48.0.2

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\2\tmpc2_p3ubt If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

When I try to run my Python script, Firefox is timing out. Does anyone have any suggestions on which versions i need to match?

Comment: It wont, Its known issue, You should be using Gecko Driver from now on for Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall current firefox version than Download Firefox from this link https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/46.0.1/win64-EME-free/en-GB/Firefox%20Setup%2046.0.1.exe and then try again

Note : you have to uncheck automatic upgrade of firefox after install of 46 using below setps:

1. Goto Options
2. Goto advance
3. Under Firefox updates: Never check for updates (not recommended: security risk)

   If you want to run on firefox >= 48 then you need to upgrade to selenium 3beta. https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2016/07/29/announcing-selenium-3-0-beta1/

Answer (score 0):

It wont and its a known issue, Refer thread here
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2559

> Can't fix.
>
> In Firefox 48, Mozilla requires extensions to be signed. They have
>   refused to sign Selenium's Firefox driver extension (webdriver.xpi).
>   Feel free to contact them and/or log an issue for them at
>   https://bugzilla.mozilla.org
>
> The way forward now is to use GeckoDriver. Which is now the default
>   implementation used in 3.0-beta
>
> This issue has been known as a long time coming, I highly recommend
>   pinning your automation to use Firefox 45 ESR until a release of using
>   GeckoDriver/marionette is stable enough for your tests.

Gecko Driver is a way forward.